# How to convert list of timestamp columns in Python Pandas with Time zone offset 1) Convert to UTC 2) Convert to EST 3) Remove TZ offset & store as is

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, timezone

How to convert list of timestamp columns in Python Pandas with Time zone offset

1. Convert to UTC value without TZ offset
2. Convert to  EST value without TZ offset
3. Just Remove TZ offset & store as is

I have list of four columns in a Pandas Data frame which has Timestamp with Time zone offset as follows:
**ts_lst** = [SLA_START_TIME, SLA_STOP_TIME, RES_START_TIME, RES_STOP_TIME]
Sample value : **2017-06-27T09:30:19.757-0400**

For each of the columns in the ts_lst what is the optimal solution to

1. Convert UTC Time zone to EST
2. Remove the Time zone offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for column in [x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("time", case=False)]]:
    df[column] = (
        pd.to_datetime(df[column], utc=True)
        .dt.tz_convert("America/New_York")
        .dt.tz_localize(None)
        .dt.floor("S")
    )
```